# DS160 online form - Arrival flight

Tags: transit, applications, flight-status

I am filling out the DS160 application form for USA transit visa ( C1 ).
On my travel plans I need to put "Arrival flight (if known)" my question might be stupid, but what do I need to put there?
The name of the flight ex. DL 12
or maybe LHR>ATL or I need to specify the time of my arrival ex. 4:12PM
Tickets are bought so I have all the information about my flight.
Please if anyone has an answer, it will be highly appreciated.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Arrival flight is the flight segment that arrives in the US. You should specify its flight number, date and scheduled time of arrival.